# Issue requesting YouTube API JSON feed via JavaScript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, youtube-api

I have been using the youtube api and javascript to generate a player area and then arrows that allow the user to click and scroll through videos to play a new one in the player area. This works fine in every other browser except ie, where it appears to be playing up in ie7,8 and 9 but only on some Operating Systems. For example it appears to be fine using the simulator in windows 8.. any help?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bBCG/ (which for some reason isn't working here, think the json feed may not be working - but the code does work)

Heres the bit where I'm retrieving the feed:

```
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/BadbyMicroMovies/uploads?v=2&alt=json';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';

$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
    var list_data="";
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
        list_data += '<li><a class="vid-link" href="'+ url +'?rel=0" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"</a></li>';
    });
    $(list_data).appendTo("#youtube-feed");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am flumoxed!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9bBCG/1/

Comment: Can you explain what you have done to this to get it work with i.e. exactly?.. as I can't tell in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Changed onload to no wrap in head

Comment: The js is being loaded externally in it's own file from the head section in i.e. already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer only started supporting standard [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in version 10. If you're using an older version of Internet Explorer, you can't directly request a resource on a different domain using `XMLHttpRequest` (which is what that `$.getJSON()` call is doing).

Instead, you need to use an approach like [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which will also work on other browsers. You can do this by using a `$.ajax()` call instead of `$.getJSON()`, and specify the `dataType: 'jsonp'` parameter, as explain in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: For one thing, there's a syntax problem with how you're passing in your parameters to $.ajax(). The first parameter is a JavaScript object, and you're missing the {} around the properties of the object. I'm not sure if there are any other problems as well.